Error: TypeError: Invalid URL when try to create Hono cloudflare project using npm
Error Image
npm create hono@latest my-app

node:internal/url:797
    this.#updateContext(bindingUrl.parse(input, base));
                                   ^

TypeError: Invalid URL
    at new URL (node:internal/url:797:36)
    at #getUrl (C:\Users\somal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:23827:77)
    at new ProxyAgent (C:\Users\somal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:23794:36)
    at new UndiciProxyAgent (C:\Users\somal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:28530:9)
    at createProxy (C:\Users\somal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:28576:160)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\somal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:30620:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',
  input: 'prajwal'
}

Node.js v20.17.0
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Prajwal\coding\Harkirath Cohort\Practice\week-11
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-hono my-app
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\somal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-31T06_24_27_899Z-debug-0.log

I am getting this error when I tried to create project using hono and i am getting the same type of error when I try to create simple cloudflare worker project.
I updated node and try to run it but again I am getting same error.
Please can anyone tell me what's the issue here.

The TypeError: Invalid URL occurred because the http_proxy environment variable was set to an invalid value (prajwal). This incorrect value caused issues with URL handling in Node.js, preventing the create-hono command from executing properly. By removing the erroneous http_proxy configuration, you allowed the command to bypass the faulty proxy settings, enabling it to perform HTTP requests directly and successfully complete its task. This experience underscores the need for correct proxy configuration when using environment variables that affect network operations.
